# Can I make last item of sitemapPath control not clickable? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, sitemappath, web.sitemap

I am using asp.net built-in SitemapPath control as a breadcrumbs bar on a site. SitemapPath get the data from Web.Sitemap file. At the moment, if you click on the last item on the SitemapPath which will reload the same page again.

Can I make the last item of SitemapPath not clickable but other items still clickable to avoid users clicking on that last item.

Thanks,

L

Comment: The documentation suggests that `RenderCurrentNodeAsLink` is the property you're looking for, but the default value is `false`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.rendercurrentnodeaslink.aspx

Comment: OH Great ,, i overlooked this property .. that's the one I am looking for .. thanks ..

Comment: you are welcome to promote your answer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.rendercurrentnodeaslink.aspx) suggests that [`RenderCurrentNodeAsLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.rendercurrentnodeaslink.aspx) is the property you're looking for, but the default value is `false`.